# How can I make socket sendto() block if the receiver's rcvbuf is full under UDP?

Tags: sockets

So I'm trying to send 100000 udp packets to a server, about 20bytes each.
My server needs to do some processing for each packet, so now it seems like the rcvbuf can only hold ~1000 packets since the server is receiving too slow and I guess the rest of the packets are being dropped because of it.

Is there anyway to tell if the receiver's packet queue is full so that I can have my sender wait on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

By definition, UDP is an unreliable datagram protocol, with no flow control whatsoever.

If you want the sender to block when the receiver is full, use a TCP connection. UDP is connectionless. The sender has no information on the status of the receiver. All the sender does is send packets. UDP provides no feedback, whatsoever, on the receiver's status. If you want to implement any kind of flow control, you have to engineer it yourself, on top of UDP.